# change json creating from form

Tags: javascript, json

I write this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        var voter = [];
        var voted_questions = [];
        var answers = [];

        $('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(){
            voted_questions.push($(this).data('questionid'));
            answers.push({'question':$(this).data('questionid'),'options':this.value});
        });

        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
            voted_questions.push($(this).data('questionid'));
            answers.push({'question':$(this).data('questionid'),'options':this.value});
        });

        $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
            voted_questions.push($(this).data('questionid'));
            answers.push({'question':$(this).data('questionid'),'custom':this.value});
        });

        $('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){
            if ($(this).data('voter') == 'ip_address')        
            voter.push({'ip_address':this.value});
            if ($(this).data('voter') == 'voting_started')        
            voter.push({'voting_started':this.value});
            if ($(this).data('voter') == 'voting_ended')        
            voter.push({'voting_ended':this.value});
        });

        var data = {
            'voter': voter,
            'voted_questions': voted_questions,
            'answers': answers
        };

        $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(data));
        return false;
    });

});
```

Demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/B9r22/5

I don't know how to delete `[]` from `voter`.  I would like to have json like this:

```
'voter': 
{
'ip_address': a.b.c.d, 
'voting_started':voting_started, 
'voting_ended': voting_ended,
}
```

Comment: Change your array to an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making `voter` as an array (`[]`) and then pushing objects into it.  To get what you want, make `voter` an object (`{}`) and add the key/value pairs you want.

```
var voter = {};

$('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){
    if ($(this).data('voter') == 'ip_address')        
        voter.ip_address = this.value;
    if ($(this).data('voter') == 'voting_started')        
        voter.voting_started = this.value;
    if ($(this).data('voter') == 'voting_ended')        
        voter.voting_ended = this.value;
});
```

Comment: thank you it works, but I find out next problem, I have this there input[type="checkbox"]:checked ... but for input[type="text"]:checked it´s not working, why and what is solution?

Comment: @user3357400: text inputs can't be checked.  What are you trying to do?